# why is form_with resulting in a NoMethodError in Articles#new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the getting started section in the rails guides to build a blog. I have reached the first form section 5.2 and when loading the page i get:

```
NoMethodError in Articles#new

Showing C:/Sites/blog/app/views/articles/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `form_with' for #<#<Class:0x8a44a18>:0xaf1d990>

Extracted source (around line #1):

<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>
```

Is form_with a relatively new method in rails? because i thought form normally use form_for or form_tag.

I installed rails a few months ago and i am using version 5.0.6.

1) should i update to the latest version?

2) is this a case of simply updating the rails gem in this project or something more complicated?

3) if i update will this affect other projects i am running locally and/or in production?

4) is there another reason why this form_with is not working

Comment: post the controller code and I am sure you can get the answer

Comment: @RockwellRicecontroller code is just an empty 'new' method for now which would go to the 'new' view which contains the form_with method. so the controller doesnt really contain any useful information

Answer (score 3):

From the [Rails 5.1 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#unification-of-form-for-and-form-tag-into-form-with):

> Before Rails 5.1, there were two interfaces for handling HTML forms: `form_for` for model instances and `form_tag` for custom URLs.
>
> Rails 5.1 combines both of these interfaces with `form_with`, and can generate form tags based on URLs, scopes or models.

So yes, `form_with` is fairly recent and not available in Rails 5.0.6.

You could upgrade (the latest is 5.1.4) or switch to `form_tag`.

Comment: 1) is this a case of simply updating the rails gem in this project's Gemfile  or something more complicated?

2) if i update will this affect other projects i am running locally and/or in production?

Comment: There may be other changes needed when upgrading from 5.0.6 to 5.1.4, check the release notes and changelogs. Upgrading just this one project shouldn't affect others that you're running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the form_tag syntax, then you will also have to change the syntax for input fields as follows:

```
<%= form_tag scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:title) %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag(:title) %>
  </p>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem running Rails, as 4.2.1 . I needed to update Rails, **but also** to escape my package manager's (apt) repository, which was outdated. This led me to the rvm mananger, the Ruby Version Manager (https://rvm.io/). Depending on your operating system, you will have a different guide here: http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html.

You may be experiencing  a development environment without the most current version of all the gems that are needed for development. As is stated in updating rails link : "Developers often install the newest version of Rails but neglect other components needed for Rails to run successfully."

Also I advise starting the tutorial from the beginning creating a `rails new blog`after updating to ensure you are not using the Gemfile specifications from your previous build.